# Issue with PHP regex trying to detect the less-than and greater than characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a simple form requesting a Username and a Password.  The regex should detect the presence of one or more of either the less than or greater than character.
Everything functions correctly with the greater than, but the less than causes a cut-off/stoppage of the error feed back message.

Example: 
If I enter 'road' as username and 'w>ay' as a password, I get:

```
road is good to go
Your entry: "w>ay" contains illegal characters.
Please re-enter, and be sure the < or the > are not present.
```

Now, if I enter `'w<ay'` instead, I get:

```
road is good to go
Your entry: "wPlease re-enter, and be sure the < or the > are not present.
```

I am stumped.

Code:

```
<?php

function characterEntryCheck($dataEntered)
{
$illegal="/[><]+/"; 


    if(preg_match($illegal, $dataEntered))
    {
        echo "Your entry: \"" . $dataEntered . "\" contains illegal characters." .     "<br>";
        echo "Please re-enter, and be sure the < or the > are not present." ."<br>";
        exit;
    }
    else{

        echo $dataEntered . " is good to go" . "<br>"; // feedback for testing only
    }
}




    /* Variable passed from input data fields in form */

    $name=$_POST["u"];
    $password=$_POST["p"];





    if(!empty($name)&&!empty($password))  // has data has been entered?
    {
        characterEntryCheck($name);
        characterEntryCheck($password);




    }else{
        echo "Please enter data in all of the fields";  // feedback for testing only
    }
```

?>

Comment: Why are you prohibiting them from using `>` in their passwords?  Are you trying to stop HTML injection?  That's not the way to do it.

Comment: No, it's just an exercise requirement that those two specific characters can not be accepted.

Comment: Here's something odd...

Comment: the last line in my question should read: Now, if I enter 'w<ay' instead, I get:
road is good to go
Your entry: "wPlease re-enter, and be sure the < or the > are not present.

Comment: Wouldn't let me edit that...hmmmm

Comment: @cook27 The reason you were having problems with the question is the same basic reason you are having problems with your PHP. `<` is a special character in HTML, and the browser is treating it as the start of a tag. This can have dangerous results, as discussed in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `<` is breaking your output, because you are not escaping the output correctly. Wrap `$dataEntered` in `htmlspecialchars()` before echoing:

```
echo "Your entry: \"" . htmlspecialchars($dataEntered) . "\" contains illegal characters." .     "<br>";
```

Note that if you don't do this and somebody enters a username like `<script>evil_javascript_commands...</script>`, your site has just been subjected to [Cross-Site Scripting (XSS)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29), which can have some surprisingly nasty effects.

Comment: `htmlspecialchars` is much safer, allowing `htmlentities` for something like this is a huge risk.

Comment: Thanks so much Ed Cottrell and l'L'l

Answer (score 0):

You need to use htmlspecialchars:

```
htmlspecialchars($dataEntered, ENT_QUOTES);
```